# How to access the QR Code data programatically in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, qr-code

Can we access the scanned data from QR Code in Windows Phone 7?

Comment: While you are not obliged to accept any particular answer, if you accept answers then it helps anyone else who reads your question and needs an answer. Doing this also rewards the person who made the correct answer, and you do want to thank them, right? Above all, don't treat the site as your own personal help desk. If you want to participate in the community then do your bit, read this for a guideline: [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access the built-in QR code scanner but you can build one yourself in less than 150 lines of code as [this blog post](http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/qr-code-scanning-on-windows-phone-75-using-zxlib/) claims. The solution uses the [ZXing image processing library for WP7](https://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/) (this does the QR code detection). [Demo source code](https://github.com/follesoe/WinPhoneSamples/tree/master/ScannerDemo), as linked to in the blog post.